# How to POST to a rest api and consume the non ending stream in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to consume a stream of a rest api. The thing is that this stream is continuous and i need to POST some JSON to it, so it knows what to stream back.

Can you guys help me? This is what i have right now, but the problem is that the _httpClient.PostAsync() is never completing.

```
    var content = new StringContent("whatever", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("URL", content);

    //not reaching this point here

    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Comment: i don't think is it possible to have a non ending stream because HTTP is stateless connection .it means it will close connection after a specific time .btw interesting .

Comment: HTML witch REST relies on is connection less and therefore can not support streams. You need to leverage some supporting technology.

Comment: You mean http. Html is markup language :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it will help you, but you can tell the HTTPClient whether to wait for the complete response, or only for the headers, if you use the SendAsync method:

```cs
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "URL");
request.Content = new StringContent("whatever", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not recommended to use http for this purpose, but you can achieve it with this code

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "URL");
request.Content = new StringContent("whatever", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

the key part here is `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` which completes `SendAsync` as soon as the response stream is ready.